# empty brace-init-lists emit warnings about missing field initializers

Tags: c++, c++11

Goal: to be able list-initialize objects and to have the default
initialization init all PODs to 0/`false` with as little boilerplate
as possible (C++11).

Assume I have several classes with several PODs (think of file format
parsing). In order not to deal with undefined values I would like the
default constructed objects to be value-initialized to 0. For example,
providing my own default c'tor that `memset()`s `this` works fine for
such cases, as does naming all members explicitely.

However, this is boilerplate. Even more importantly providing my own
argument-less default constructor prevents me from using the list
initializer syntax for member initialization:

```
class Fails1 {
public:
  int a, b;
  Fails1() { memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this)); }
};

Fails1 this_works;
Fails1 this_fails{ 42, 54 }; // compiler error
```

I could add the constructor for the `initializer_list` as well, but
that's even more boilerplate. I want to avoid all that boilerplate.

So I looked at the default constructors provided by the compiler when
there's no user-provided default constructor in combination with the
various methods how one can initialize them. Here's where I got
totally confused:

```
class A {
public:
  int a, b;
};
```

With this class I can use both empty initialization lists and those
with values without having to provide both constructors myself; that
is part of what I want.

```
// Example 1: default initialization
A a1;
```

The first example uses initialization; members `a` and `b` are
undefined afterwards (not what I want, I want them to be
value-initialized).

```
// Example 2: Value-initialization, so this works, I guess:
A a2 = A();
```

Example 2 uses value initialization and does not copy afterwards. So that is what I want, however, I also thought that empty brace-init-lists would do the same; see the following example:

```
// Example 3: list-initialization with empty brace-init-list
A a3{};
```

Example 3 is what I thought would do the trick. List initialization
with an empty brace-init-list is described in 8.5.4
"List-initialisation":; especially 8.5.4.3 says: "If the initializer
list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor,
the objectvalue-initialized". However, this issues warnings with g++ 4.7.2
with `-Wextra`:

```
missing initializer for member ‘A::a’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
missing initializer for member ‘A::b’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
```

No warnings by clang++ 3.1, though, so it may also be a bug in g++.

So back to my original question. How do I value-initialize an object
without having to provide my own boilerplatish default constructor --
while retaining the ability to use list-initialization for its members
without having to provide my own `initializer_list` constructor?

Comment: I don't find `A() : a{}, b{} {}` too boilerplate-ish, but it would be better if those warnings weren't there and `A a{}` compiled without warnings.

Comment: Providing the default ctor also requires me to provide a `initializer_list` default ctor. Now multiply that with > 20 header fields per class times > 10 classes and I'd definitely call that boilerplatish. Of course that's in the eye of the beholder, so my boilerplate may very well be your normal coding style, and that is perfectly OK :)

Comment: Using `memset` in a constructor is not allowed at all in C++03, because the presence of a user defined constructor makes the class non-POD. In C++11 this is *somewhat* relaxed, and therefore allowed in some cases. However, I see a big gun aiming straight at your foot.

Comment: @MoritzBunkus, At that point, I'd probably disable the warning, to be honest. It doesn't pertain to what you're doing.

Comment: @BoPersson: OK, wasn't aware of that, but that makes my question even more important to me in order not to produce as much boilerplate.

Comment: @chris: so is what you're saying that the empty brace-init-list should work just as I expected it to work in my question and that warning is a bug in g++?

Comment: @MoritzBunkus, I'm leaning toward that. It's just trying to help out by saying you forgot some, but I guess it doesn't recognize empty lists very well.

Comment: If the types are aggregates, you can simply write `A a = {};` (note the `=` sign, which signals copy initialization).  This has the added advantage of working with C++03 as well.

Comment: `struct A { int a,b; };`, followed by `A a {};` is clearly aggregate initialization and implies value-initialization (i.e. zero-initialization). The GCC warning is very misleading; when searching for existing bug reports, I found [this one](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55805), which you've filed yourself. I think that was the right thing to do.

Comment: @jogojapan: yeah I filed that after the initial comments here. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: +1 for misleading gcc warning. I go for `mystruct s{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};` but it's hideous...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A plain struct like

```
struct A { int a,b; };
```

is clearly an aggregate, and `A a {};` is clearly aggregate initialization and implies value-initialization (i.e. zero-initialization), as described by §8.5.4/3 quoted by you already. (Note in particular the example given there in the following paragraph, which is practically identical to your situation.)

The GCC warning is very misleading.

When searching for existing bug reports, I found [this one](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55805), which you've filed yourself. I think that was the right thing to do.

Since you've worked out the relevant Standard sections already, and various other people contributed in the comments, I'll make this a Community Wiki answer.

Answer (score 4):

gcc's warning about missing initializers is more a disservice than anything else: If there is an initializer list, values are filled from the list and remaining fields are zero initialized. Thus, with an empty initializer list all values are zero initialized. It may be reasonable to warn about a non-empty initializer list which doesn't mention all members: I have seen errors where programmers had provided a non-zero initializer for the first element of an array and assumed that the initializer would be repeated for all remaining values.

With respect to creating initialization by default while also allowing an initializer list, I'd use an initializing template for basic types:

```
template <typename T>
struct init
{
    init(): value_() {}
    template <typename S> init(S&& value): value_(std::forward<S>(value)) {}
    T value_;
};

struct foo
{
    init<int>    i_;
    init<double> d_;
    std::string  s_;
};

int main()
{
    foo f0;
    foo f1 = { 1, 3.14, "foo" };
    foo f2 = { };
}
```

This approach guarantees that the members are initialized independent on how the objects of the class are used while also supporting the use of an initializer list. gcc still, incorrectly, warns about missing initializers, though.

Comment: Thanks for the information & providing that fail-safe alternative.